# Как правильно сверстать блок?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок шириной `1180px`. В этом блоке находится картинка с абсолютным позиционированием, и выходящая за границы блока в правую сторону. Если размер окна браузера допустим `1180px`, то появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки. Как правильно сделать вёрстку, чтобы полоса прокрутки появлялась только при ширине окна меньше `1180px` и прокручивала страницу по горизонтали только на ту часть, которая не вместилась у блока с шириной `1180px`?

Или есть только одно решение? Полностью убрать горизонтальную полосу прокрутки (`overflow-x:hidden`).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, всё просто.
Оборачиваем в блок с

```
min-width: 1180px; 
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще стоит добавить, что когда у нас есть задача подвязаная на ширину экрана устройства, то целесообразно использовать медиа запросы.

Comment: Я думаю в моём случае медиазапрос будет лишним.